# Как сделать так, чтобы работал слайдер

Tags: jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как исправить ошибку? Не работает слайдер.
Пробовала заменять SlideUp и SlideToggle на show и hid, но в этом случае работает не так, как нужно

Comment: У Вас там скобки неправильно расставлены: после ($(this) не хватает, а после next() лишняя

Comment: Здравствуйте! Оставляйте в следующий раз не скриншот скрипта, а сам скрипт

Comment: пробовала менять и скобки все равно выдает ошибку:
TypeError: $('.block__text').not($(this).next()).slideUp is not a function. (In '$('.block__text').not($(this).next()).slideUp(300)', '$('.block__text').not($(this).next()).slideUp' is undefined)

Comment: Вы ничего не поменяли. Вот так надо - после $(this) добавить, а после $(next) убрать: $('.block__text').not($(this)).next().slideUp(300)

Comment: так?


$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.block__title').click(function () {
  if ($('.block').hasClass('one')) {
   $('.block__title').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
   $('.block__text').not($(this)).next().slideUp(300);
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle(300);
 });
});